# Why I can not export animations from AssimpLoader to GLTFExporter?

Tags: javascript, three.js, export

I want export model from AssimpLoader to GLTFExporter
I used

```
const loader = new AssimpLoader();
loader.load(url, function ( result ) {
    const object = result.object;
    object.position.y = - 100;
    object.rotation.x = Math.PI * 2;
    group.add(object)
    animation = result.animation;
    export_animates = [result.animation]
    console.log(result.animation)
} );

function ani() { 
    if ( animation ) animation.setTime( performance.now() / 1000 );
}

    const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter();

    const options = {
        trs: document.getElementById( 'option_trs' ).checked,
        onlyVisible: document.getElementById( 'option_visible' ).checked,
        truncateDrawRange: document.getElementById( 'option_drawrange' ).checked,
        binary: document.getElementById( 'option_binary' ).checked,
        animations: export_animates,
        maxTextureSize: Number( document.getElementById( 'option_maxsize' ).value ) || Infinity // To prevent NaN value
    };
    gltfExporter.parse( input, function ( result ) {

        if ( result instanceof ArrayBuffer ) {
            console.log(result)

        } else {

            const output = JSON.stringify( result, null, 2 );
            // generate object output
            console.log(output)
            
            //saveString( output, 'scene.gltf' );

        }

    }, options );
```

but i get error

> AssimpLoader.js:302  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'name')

When i try  export  from FBX to GLTF.
It is work.
What am i doing wrong?